# Java set a specific field based on input

Tags: java, java-8

Not sure how to really explain it in title but here goes.

My `POJO`,

```java
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
public class TestPOJO {

    private int field1;
    private int field2;
    private int field3;
    private int field4;

    public static TestPOJOBuilder builder(final String config) {
        final TestPOJOBuilder builder = new TestPOJOBuilder();
        // Magic Here 
       
        return builder;
    }
}
```

So basically what i what to achieve is that based on the user input config, set the field which is needed.

Let us say that i have a mapping such as,

```
Config1 -> Field1
Config2 -> Field2
Config3 -> Field3
Config4 -> Field3
Config5 -> Field4
```

I don't want user to be aware of this config. They should just trust that if i pass the correct config value then correct field would be set (assume setting is 1, otherwise 0).

So creating the builder like so,

```
TestPOJO.builder("Config4").build()
```

should give me a TestPOJO object with `field3` set.

Is this possible without reflection since i am inside the class and should have access to all members?

I'm on `Java8`.

Comment: "Is this possible without reflection" Nope. Reflection only.

Comment: Maybe you are overthinking this, but if you already have the mapping you are probably close to the solution. How do you define what is a valid value and to which field should it go? (is that static or dynamic?). I bet some if blocks may do the trick.

Comment: Shouldn't your _builder_ method be returning a _TestPOJO_?

Comment: "Shouldn't your builder method be returning a TestPOJO?" No, that's for a build() method

Comment: Oh, never mind, I was reading it as _build_ not _builder_.

Comment: @AleZalazar The config is fixed. So i was thinking of making a map of string to "consumer"? or something so that i can just do `configMap.get(config).accept()` or something similar. If statements or switch case seem to be my only solution at the moment since i don't want to use reflection.

Comment: The consumer/accept strategy looks good to me (I believe you mean Consumer instances that require a list of valid values to be instantiated), the only restriction I see is having to implement everything in the TestPOJO class or having to pass your TestPOJO instance to the accept method as a parameter, having setters for each field, etc

Comment: Reflection is tempting as it allows to achieve the goal with less code than a `switch` over the string or a `Map`, however, it’s a dangerous thing to allow external input to cause  access to arbitrary members without limiting it to the fields you actually intended.

Answer (score 0):

A simple switch statement inside the builder method could do the trick:

```
public TestPOJO builder(String field) {
    switch(field) {
       case "Config1":
           setField1(...);
           break;
       case "Config2":
           setField2(...);
           break;
       case "Config3":
           setField3(...);
           break;
       ...
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: This is what i want to avoid is possible since my config can grow and this will increase branching.

Answer (score 0):

Not super pretty but i ended up doing this way

```java
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
public class TestPOJO {
    private static final Map<String, Consumer<TestPOJOBuilder>> CONFIG_MAP = 
         ImmutableMap.<String, Consumer<TestPOJOBuilder>>builder()
             .put("Config1", builder -> builder.field1(1))
             .put("Config2", builder -> builder.field2(1))
             .put("Config3", builder -> builder.field3(1))
             .put("Config4", builder -> builder.field3(1))
             .put("Config1", builder -> builder.field4(1))
             .build();

    private int field1;
    private int field2;
    private int field3;
    private int field4;

    public static TestPOJOBuilder builder(final String config) {
        final TestPOJOBuilder builder = new TestPOJOBuilder();
        CONFIG_MAP.get(config).accept(builder);
       
        return builder;
    }
}
```

If we need to set some other value then we can have a BiConsumer to take the input value as well.